# Pinch zoom to only part of the website

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images, mobile, zoom

I have mobile site where it should not contain pinch zoom. I have done this using below statement in head.

user-scalable property stopped the pinch zoom.

My challenge is in product details page, on clicking product image, the image will open in popup where the image should contain pinch zoom.

How to achieve pinch zoom to only image part?